# "Error is Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts" : focus is not bale to work in document,querySelector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Why focus is giving error? Error is Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts

Please can any one help me.

```
@HostListener('keydown.tab', [ '$event'])
 keyfunction(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
   // First element: always first element is h2 where tabindex avaliable.
   let focusable = document.querySelector('.modal').querySelectorAll('[tabindex],button');
   if (focusable.length) {
       const first = focusable[0];
       const last = focusable[focusable.length - 1];
       const shift = event.shiftKey;
    
       if (shift) {
         if (event.target === first) {
           last.focus();// **Error is: Error is Property 'focus' does not exist on type **
           
           event.preventDefault();
         }
     } else {
         if (event.target === last) {
            first.focus();// Getting error is here
           event.preventDefault();
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: please let me know what is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`last` and `first` have by default type `Element` because `querySelectorAll` returns value of type `NodeListOf<Element>`.

My suggestion is to change type at declaration.

```
const first: HTMLElement = focusable[0] as HTMLElement;
const last: HTMLElement = focusable[focusable.length - 1] as HTMLElement;
```